# Texture not showing in object but visible in UV editor when I draw

Tags: uv, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

So, I unwrapped my object. Then I created an image file with a certain color. In *Principled BSDF* node I added the option image texture and loaded the image.

In UV editor, I loaded the saved image. The base color of the image showed. But now I painted the object in *Texture Paint* mode it doesn't show up in object but shows up in the image in the *UV Editor*.

Can anyone please tell me what can be gone wrong??

[image: screenshot of texture paint mode]

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I think is going on:

Although the two image data blocks are from the same file, they are not the same data block, so the only way to get them in sync right now is to save to the image file and then reload everything.

What you need to do is go back to the shader and select the same image data block that is open in the image editor, by clicking the little pull down on the Image Texture node:[image: image data block selector]

Comment: I tried reloading at first it was not responding but i got texture after sometime. Anyways  Thank you for ur answer